# Using ajax after dropdown menu has changed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to select an option from the dropdown menu, then have ajax get the data from ajax.php and then output it in #output.

**script**

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $("#category_list").change(function() {
 $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#output").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $("#output").html("Error with ajax");
                    }

   });
  });
});
```

**dropdown**

```
     foreach($categories as $category) {?>
     <option><?php echo $category['categoryName']; ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
```

**ajax.php**

```
 <?php
 $result = "Ajax is working";
 echo $result;
 ?>
```

When I select an option, it gives me my "Error with ajax" error. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The problem was in the link to ajax.php. My website displays different sections from different .phps, so i got confused with what folder ajax.php is in.

Comment: when does `data` get populated? I mean, you ajax error could be because you're calling it with an undefined variable.

Comment: Catch the errors from the response
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
$('#output').html(JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + "<br />" + textStatus + "<br />" + errorThrown);
}

Comment: is #option a select element?

Comment: Swallows actual error. Expects us to guess what it was. -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to log your error form ajax object

```
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"ajax.php",
      data: "{'parameter1': 'value1'}", 
      success: function(data) { $("#output").html(data); },
      error: function(ts) { 
      alert(ts.responseText) 

      $("#output").html("Error with ajax");
      }
    })
```